# Implement nested loop with condition in Scala

Tags: java, scala

What is an idiomatic way to implement the following code in Scala?

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i+=2) {
  // i = 1, 3, 5, 7, 9
  bool intercept = false;

  for (int j = 1; j < 10; j+=3) {
    // j = 1, 4, 7
    if (i==j) intercept = true
  }

  if (!intercept) {
    System.out.println("no intercept")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Range`](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_18.html) and friends:

```
if (((1 until 10 by 2) intersect (1 until 10 by 3)).isEmpty)
  System.out.println("no intercept")
```

This doesn't involve a nested loop (which you refer to in the title), but it is a much more idiomatic way to get the same result in Scala.

Edit: As Rex Kerr points out, the version above doesn't print the message each time, but the following does:

```
(1 until 10 by 2) filterNot (1 until 10 by 3 contains _) foreach (
   _ => println("no intercept")
)
```

Comment: This has different behavior than the code example provided.  If you run the Java code you'll get `no intercept` printed three times.

Comment: Thinking as sets it would be `(1 until 10 by 2)` **minus** `(1 until 10 by 3)`. Which is achieved by the filterNot.

Answer (score 6):

Edit: whoops, you print for each `i`.  In that case:

```
for (i <- 1 until 10 by 2) {
  if (!(1 until 10 by 3).exists(_ == i)) println("no intercept")
}
```

In this case you don't actually need the condition, though: the `contains` method will check what you want checked in the inner loop.

```
for (i <- 1 until 10 by 2) {
  if (!(1 until 10 by 3).contains(i)) println("no intercept")
}
```